# How to get if a RichTextBox has text and run code

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to get if a RichTextBox has any text to run a certain code.

I tried:
 If RichTextBox1 = Text Then

But it didnt work.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have anything in RichTextBox1.Text. Because your code is not doing that

```
If RichTextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("there's no text in RichBox")
End If
```

This IF block will check whether your RichTextBox empty or not still you need to find any perticular match check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
' Obtain the location of the search string in richTextBox1. 
 Dim indexToText As Integer = RichTextBox1.Find(text)
```

You want to know multiple combination of Find check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.Find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @user3597926 He's not. If RichTextBox1.Text = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Then ....

Answer (score 0):

```
    '--------------------------IF Theres Nothing in it-----------------------------

    If RichTextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("there's no text in RichBox")
    End If

    '--------------------------IF There in it--------------------------------------


    If RichTextBox1.Text <>"" Then
        MsgBox("there's a text in RichBox")
    End If
```